# How to integrate Google wallet payment get with my app?

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
  public static final int MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE = 888;
  public static final String WALLET_FRAGMENT_ID = "wallet_fragment";
  public static final int FULL_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE = 889;
  private SupportWalletFragment mWalletFragment;
  private MaskedWallet mMaskedWallet;
  private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
  private FullWallet mFullWallet;

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WalletFragmentStyle walletFragmentStyle =
        new WalletFragmentStyle().setBuyButtonText(BuyButtonText.BUY_NOW)
            .setBuyButtonWidth(Dimension.MATCH_PARENT);

    WalletFragmentOptions walletFragmentOptions = WalletFragmentOptions.newBuilder()
        .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
        .setFragmentStyle(walletFragmentStyle)
        .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_LIGHT)
        .setMode(WalletFragmentMode.BUY_BUTTON)
        .build();

    mWalletFragment = SupportWalletFragment.newInstance(walletFragmentOptions);

    WalletFragmentInitParams.Builder startParamsBuilder = WalletFragmentInitParams.newBuilder()
        .setMaskedWalletRequest(generateMaskedWalletRequest())
        .setMaskedWalletRequestCode(MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE)
        .setAccountName("Google I/O Codelab");
    mWalletFragment.initialize(startParamsBuilder.build());

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.wallet_button_holder, mWalletFragment, WALLET_FRAGMENT_ID)
        .commit();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Wallet.API,
            new Wallet.WalletOptions.Builder().setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
                .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_LIGHT)
                .build())
        .build();

  }

  public void requestFullWallet(View view) {
    if (mMaskedWallet == null) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "No masked wallet, can't confirm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return;
    }
    Wallet.Payments.loadFullWallet(mGoogleApiClient,
        generateFullWalletRequest(mMaskedWallet.getGoogleTransactionId()),
        FULL_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
  }



  @Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
      case MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE:
        switch (resultCode) {
          case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            mMaskedWallet = data.getParcelableExtra(WalletConstants.EXTRA_MASKED_WALLET);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Got Masked Wallet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
          case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            // The user canceled the operation
            break;
          case WalletConstants.RESULT_ERROR:
            Toast.makeText(this, "An Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

          case FULL_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE:
            switch (resultCode) {
              case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                mFullWallet = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(WalletConstants.EXTRA_FULL_WALLET);
                // Show the credit card number
                Toast.makeText(this,
                    mFullWallet.getProxyCard().getPan().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Wallet.Payments.notifyTransactionStatus(mGoogleApiClient,
                    generateNotifyTransactionStatusRequest(
                        mFullWallet.getGoogleTransactionId(),
                        NotifyTransactionStatusRequest.Status.SUCCESS));

                break;
              case WalletConstants.RESULT_ERROR:
                Toast.makeText(this, "An Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;


            }
            break;


        }
        break;
    }
  }
  public static NotifyTransactionStatusRequest generateNotifyTransactionStatusRequest(
      String googleTransactionId, int status) {
    return NotifyTransactionStatusRequest.newBuilder()
        .setGoogleTransactionId(googleTransactionId)
        .setStatus(status)
        .build();
  }
  private FullWalletRequest generateFullWalletRequest(String googleTransactionId) {
    FullWalletRequest fullWalletRequest = FullWalletRequest.newBuilder()
        .setGoogleTransactionId(googleTransactionId)
        .setCart(Cart.newBuilder()
            .setCurrencyCode("USD")
            .setTotalPrice("10.10")
            .addLineItem(LineItem.newBuilder()
                .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                .setDescription("Google I/O Sticker")
                .setQuantity("1")
                .setUnitPrice("10.00")
                .setTotalPrice("10.00")
                .build())
            .addLineItem(LineItem.newBuilder()
                .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                .setDescription("Tax")
                .setRole(LineItem.Role.TAX)
                .setTotalPrice(".10")
                .build())
            .build())
        .build();
    return fullWalletRequest;
  }

  private MaskedWalletRequest generateMaskedWalletRequest() {
    MaskedWalletRequest maskedWalletRequest = MaskedWalletRequest.newBuilder()
        .setMerchantName("Google I/O Codelab")
        .setPhoneNumberRequired(true)
        .setShippingAddressRequired(true)
        .setCurrencyCode("USD")
        .setCart(Cart.newBuilder()
            .setCurrencyCode("USD")
            .setTotalPrice("10.00")
            .addLineItem(LineItem.newBuilder()
                .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                .setDescription("Google I/O Sticker")
                .setQuantity("1")
                .setUnitPrice("10.00")
                .setTotalPrice("10.00")
                .build())
            .build())
        .setEstimatedTotalPrice("15.00")
        .build();
    return maskedWalletRequest;
  }

  @Override public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

  }

  @Override public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

  }

  @Override public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

  }

  @Override public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

  }
}
```

This code i have tried but i am  able to run but i am not able to payment  using Google wallet 
i never try before Google wallet payment get-way please tell me how i will implement this is there any key or any other setting wee need  use please help me.when i try to run this code and click on BuyNow then i am getting this payment options is no longer available in this app i dont know about how i will put what setting i need to set so that i should able to pay ,

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am running into the same issue.